# How to compare items on a dataframe on pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('list.csv')
print data
```

I'm trying to get the data from this table and count the matches

Example 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMWay.png

I'm also trying to optimize code for large dataframes, filtering only tickets with more than one client:

```
double_tickets = data.TICKET.value_counts() > 1
notas_slice = double_tickets[double_tickets == True]
print notas_slice
```

I was starting on Pandas now and I do not know where to start on this problem.

EDIT:

I'd like to count the incidents between two clients. As in the image example (https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMWay.png), clients 14613 and 43733 appeared in two TICKETS at the same time, in two occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with parameter `keep=False` for return mask of all duplicates - 2 and more `TICKET` values, filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), then select by `loc` column `Client` and get values by this mask:

```
print (df.TICKET.duplicated(keep=False))
0     False
1     False
2      True
3      True
4      True
5     False
6      True
7      True
8     False
9      True
10     True
11     True
12     True
Name: TICKET, dtype: bool

print (df.loc[df.TICKET.duplicated(keep=False), 'Client'])
2     14613
3     36735
4     43733
6     24456
7     27919
9     14613
10    31725
11    37547
12    43733
Name: Client, dtype: int64
```

Then [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) if necessary filter again:

```
s = df.loc[df.TICKET.duplicated(keep=False), 'Client'].value_counts()
print (s)
43733    2
14613    2
36735    1
31725    1
37547    1
24456    1
27919    1
Name: Client, dtype: int64

print (s[s > 1])
43733    2
14613    2
Name: Client, dtype: int64
```

Last if necessary add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for convert `Series` to `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = s[s > 1].reset_index()
df1.columns = ['Client','Count']
print (df1)
   Client  Count
0   43733      2
1   14613      2
```

---

Solution with [`filtration`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration) is slowier:

```
s = df.groupby('TICKET').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)['Client'].value_counts()
print (s)
43733    2
14613    2
36735    1
31725    1
37547    1
24456    1
27919    1
Name: Client, dtype: int64
```

```
In [46]: %timeit (df.loc[df.TICKET.duplicated(keep=False), 'Client'].value_counts())
1000 loops, best of 3: 769 µs per loop

In [47]: %timeit (df.groupby('TICKET').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)['Client'].value_counts())
100 loops, best of 3: 2.55 ms per loop
```

---

```
#[1300000 rows x 2 columns]
df = pd.concat([df]*100000).reset_index(drop=True)   
#print (df)

In [53]: %timeit (df.loc[df.TICKET.duplicated(keep=False), 'Client'].value_counts())
10 loops, best of 3: 54.8 ms per loop

In [54]: %timeit (df.groupby('TICKET').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)['Client'].value_counts())
1 loop, best of 3: 282 ms per loop
```

Comment: Hummm.. 
In fact, I'd like to count the incidents between two clients. As in the image example (https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMWay.png), clients 14613 and 43733 appeared in two TICKETS at the same time, in two occurrences.